# Js как решить проблему асинхронного вызова функции

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

На сайте есть страница заказов, которые каждые 10 секунд обновляются через ajax.

```
//Автообновление заказов
window.timerId = setInterval(function () {
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        autoload: {
            "order_ids": order_ids //ID заказов для подгрузки
        }
    },
    success: loadTable //Функция отображения заказов на странице
});
}, 10000);
```

Но на странице также есть поиск заказов. И когда пользователь вводит номер заказа, старый таймер очищается и создается новый на автообновление тех заказов, что подгрузились при поиске:

```
clearInterval(window.timerId); //Выключаем предыдущее автообновление
//Дальше тот же код что и выше
```

Проблема в следующем: если ответ поиска от сервера приходит через время, то подгружается сначала результат поиска, а потом следом же подгружается старый результат автообновления (предыдущих заказов).

То-есть нужно при поиске как-то отменять подгрузку предыдущих автообновлений. Пробовал это делать через глобальную переменную, но результат похожий.

Как с таким бороться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.timerId = setInterval(function () {
  var myTimer = window.timerId;
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        autoload: {
            "order_ids": order_ids //ID заказов для подгрузки
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (myTimer == window.timerId)
        loadTable(data);
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```